# Residuals plot interpretation

Tags: r, regression, residuals

These are plots created in R. All of them are residuals (errors)
vs. fitted values. They come from multiple linear regression models fitted by least squares. The five plots represent 5 different output variables (5 different models), but they come from one dataset. All of the models use the same predictors. I would  like to ask if any conclusions can be drawn from these plots. What can be done to improve the models?

I am not very well educated in statistics and hence the only thing I can see are outliers. I am especially interested in patterns from last two plots (from first link). I added the next two plots to show that the number of data used is the same for each plot.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you explain the relationships among these plots? They look like plots for five completely different datasets or models rather than one model.

Comment: Thank you.  The appearance of the last plot suggests it is displaying only a few hundred values, while the first plot clearly reflects thousands of values. If this is the case, how can they involve the "same predictors"?  Are they perhaps from five totally different datasets where only the *meanings*--but not the values--of the predictors are the same?

Comment: (@whuber +1) Or maybe you have a lot of `NA`'s.... Also do you happen to discretize any of your response variables $y$?

Comment: There are no NA values, i checked it, always the same amount of data is used (almost 3500), the two added plots show why for some variables the data used seem to be more than for the others. All variables are continous, but they are all chnges (increments or decremens) and some of them mean change of position of some dampers. It happens that the position is constant (0 chanage) or in(de)creased always by the same amount, but in general they can take any value.

Comment: Could you provide your entire dataset, a random subset of your dataset, or simulated toy data that is qualitatively similar to your dataset?